# Consume a restful service without port in Mule

Tags: rest, mule, esb

I have a restful service deployed in public IP, and thus does not have a port number associated with it. I need to invoke that service, in mule and create a workflow.

I can consume a service with port number as specified below but am unable to do the same for a service which does not have a port number associated.

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8105" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8080" basePath="/onlineexam" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

Please help

Answer (score 5):

It will always have a port. If the URL does not have one specified then it is using the default http port '80' so set the port attribute to 80.

Comment: what about https services

Comment: https would be 443

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the issue despite adding default port 443 for my HTTPS request. Usually this issue persists when the hostname ends with `.io` or `.org`. Mine was `.io`

Adding this inside the `<http:request >` block helped:

```
<http:request-builder>
            <http:header headerName="Host" value="hostname"/>
</http:request-builder>
```

This will overrirde the configuration host and port. So you would still have to mention host and port number in the request configuration which will be overridden.

For `http`, use port **80** and for `HTTPS`, use port **443**